# How does CakePHP 3 build the cakephp-plugins.php file?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I'm having some issues installing and configuring a plugin, and I think if I had a better idea of how things worked I might be able to figure it out?!

When I install the [cakemanager/cakephp-settings](https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-settings) plugin via composer it adds to my vendor folder a 'cakemanager' folder with 3 sub-folders: 'cakephp-settings', 'cakephp-utils' (a dependency) and 'Settings'.  The 'cakephp-settings' folder is essentially empty, and all the plugin files are in the 'Settings' folder.

However, when I try to run the migrations I get an error that it cant find the /vendor/cakemanager/cakephp-settings/config/bootstrap.php file - no small wonder as this file doesnt exist!  Same error pretty much everywhere in my application

In the vendor/cakephp-plugins.php file I have this:

```
'Settings' => $baseDir . '/vendor/cakemanager/cakephp-settings/',
```

If I temporarily change this to

```
'Settings' => $baseDir . '/vendor/cakemanager/Settings/',
```

I can get the migrations done and my pages look normal again, however this reverts when I run composer dumpautoload and causes further issues down the track - I need a permanent solution.

How do I edit the plugin (composer.json files?) so that it builds the cakephp-plugins.php file correctly and it looks in the correct path for the bootstrap.php file?

Comment: Do you have `composer/installers` installed by any chance?

Comment: Yes, and the plugin composer.json has the following in it as well, which I believe relates to composer/installers from reading the readme.md? - "extra": {
    "installer-name": "Settings"
  },

Comment: Correct, and that's where the problem stems from.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try to push merging **[this pull request](https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-settings/pull/17)**, as that will fix the problem at its root, the `installer-name` option in the plugins `composer.json` will cause the target folder to be named "incorrectly" in case `composer/installers` is installed.

There is no reason to change the folder name, and as of Version 3, CakePHP doesn't need `composer/installers` anymore, so removing the option should fix the problem.

You could also try to remove `composer/installers` if you don't actually need it. In case that isn't possible, you should also be able to work around the problem by specifying the actual path via the `Plugin::load()` calls `path` option:

```
Plugin::load('Settings', [
    'path' => ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'cakemanager' . DS . 'Settings'
]);
```

It may also be worth reporting the problem to **https://github.com/cakephp/plugin-installer** and/or **https://github.com/composer/installers**, maybe it's possible to get them working together with respect to the `installer-name` option.

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Core\Plugin::load()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Core.Plugin.html#_load)**